# Why is folding partial disabled in .snippets filetypes?

Tags: folding

Something I commonly do in files is add a modeline that says use this `{{{...}}}` pattern to delimit regions to be folded:

```
# vim: foldmethod=marker
```

When vim first opens the file, the text inside the `{{{...}}}` will be folded and I will get an overview of the sections of the file.
I can then use "file wide" commands to target all the folded sections, `zm` and `zr`, or just toggle a specific region with commands like `zc` or `zo`.

#### Something worth mentioning

I am running the [ultisnips](https://github.com/sirver/UltiSnips) plugin, with snipmate type snippet files in `~/.vim/snippets`.

#### The problem

When I have a snippet file in `~/.vim/snippets` whose filetype is snippets. e.g. something like this:
`filename: ~/.vim/snippets/html.snippets`

```
# vim: foldmethod=marker

# Global snippets

# HTML {{{
snippet font_oswald
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:700,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
snippet font_oswald_style
    .oswald {
        font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 0em;
        word-spacing: 0em;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
snippet font_roboto
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
snippet font_roboto_style
    .roboto {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 900;
        text-transform: none;
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 0em;
        word-spacing: 0em;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
# }}}
```

vim is not automatically folding the text when I open this file and the "file wide" command `zm` and `zr` dont work, but the fold specific commands `zc` or `zo` do still work.
The modeline setting is being recognised, i.e `:set foldmethod?` returns

```
foldmethod=marker
```

How can I get the "normal" behaviour to work in `snippet` files?

#### update

well I know its something to do with the `ultisnips` plugin as the problem goes away when I disable ultisnips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is caused by this file in the ultisnips plugin:

```
~/.vim/bundle/UltiSnips/ftplugin/snippets.vim
```

particularly this block of code:

```
" Set some sane defaults for snippet files

if exists('b:did_ftplugin')
    finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1

let s:save_cpo = &cpo
set cpo&vim

" Fold by syntax, but open all folds by default
setlocal foldmethod=syntax
setlocal foldlevel=99

setlocal commentstring=#%s

setlocal noexpandtab
setlocal autoindent nosmartindent nocindent
```

I considered trying to disable this code by adding something like:

```
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

in my `~/.vimrc`, but I suspect this `did_ftplugin` is scoped to a buffer?
So my solution so far has been to add this modeline to any snippet files

```
# vim: foldmethod=marker foldlevel=1
```

When I open the files the code is not folded, but I can fold it all with: `zM`